# Error while using Get methode for variable transfert

Tags: php, variables, url, get, transfer

I am trying to transfer 2 parameters idpro and prixprod to the web page ajouter_prix.php. I have been thinking about a problem of concatenation. 
Where I am running my code, I get only idpro displayed in the URL. Any help please.

Below is my code:

```
<form action="ajouter_prix.php" method="post">
         <tr><td><div>Incrimenter prix: <input type="number" min="1"  name="prixprod" value="" size="1"  ></div></td></tr>
                 <?php     
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="datefin" value="'.$ligne['datea'].'"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idpro" value="'.$ligne['idpro'].'"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="prix" value="'.$ligne['prix'].'"/>';
                    echo' <a href="ajouter_prix.php?idpro='.$ligne['idpro'].'"&prixprod="'.$ligne['idpro'].'">Enchérir</a>';
        }
     ?> 
     </form></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take this as an example:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
<form action="#" method="post">
         Incrimenter prix: <input type="number" min="1"  name="prixprod" value="" size="1"  ></div></td></tr>
                 <?php     
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="datefin" value="datea"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idpro" value="idpro"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="prix" value="prix"/>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';

     ?> 
</form>
```

that returns

```
array (size=4)
  'prixprod' => string '' (length=0)
  'datefin' => string 'datea' (length=5)
  'idpro' => string 'idpro' (length=5)
  'prix' => string 'submit' (length=6)
```

if you want to take the values in a $_GET array you need to change your form method as follows:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
<form action="#" method="get">
         <tr><td><div>Incrimenter prix: <input type="number" min="1"  name="prixprod" value="" size="1"  ></div></td></tr>
                 <?php     
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="datefin" value="datea"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idpro" value="idpro"/>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="prix" value="prix"/>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';

     ?> 
</form>
```

This will return:

```
array (size=5)
  'prixprod' => string '' (length=0)
  'datefin' => string 'datea' (length=5)
  'idpro' => string 'idpro' (length=5)
  'prix' => string 'prix' (length=4)
  'submit' => string 'submit' (length=6)
```

and you'll have the query string attached to your url:

```
http://localhost/test.php?prixprod=&datefin=datea&idpro=idpro&prix=prix&submit=submit#
```

you can take the single values in your `ajouter_prix.php` file by something like this:

```
echo $_POST['datefin']; //for POST method

echo $_GET['datefin']; //for GET method
```